# ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2) when using dynamic options in form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a ChoiceField with Django Forms to set up a dropdown field for category selection that should be updated dynamically whenever a category is added. For the dynamic update I use the **init** function of the Form:

```
class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    title=forms.CharField(xxx)
    description = forms.CharField(xxx)
    URL = forms.CharField(xxx)
    starting_price = forms.IntegerField(xxx)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[value['category'] for value in Category.objects.all().values('category')])
```

The Category object is a model with a single entry, namely `category = models.CharField()`. Now, in the Django doc it mentions that any iterable for `choices` will work. So in theory a list should work (the above gives me a list like so `['furniture', 'appliances', 'cars']`).

However, I get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

I also have tried to wrap the list in a `list()` statement, same outcome.
Trying a tuple like so `([value['category'] for value in Category.objects.all().values('category')],)` which shouldn't make sense, gives the same outcome.

Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some fiddling found the answer. I have to pass a list of tuples consisting of the value of the primary key (id) and the category like so:

```
[(value['id'],value['category']) for value in Category.objects.all().values()]
```